# Understanding the "Median" in this Graph

Tags: r, data-visualization

I tried running the TSP in R using the following code (https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/132872_620c10f340f348b88453d75ec99960ff.html):

```
library(GA)
data("eurodist", package = "datasets")
D <- as.matrix(eurodist)


tourLength <- function(tour, distMatrix) {
   tour <- c(tour, tour[1])
   route <- embed(tour, 2)[,2:1]
   sum(distMatrix[route])
}

#Fitness function to be maximized

tspFitness <- function(tour, ...) 1/tourLength(tour, ...)

GA <- ga(type = "permutation", fitness = tspFitness, distMatrix = D,
          min = 1, max = attr(eurodist, "Size"), popSize = 50, maxiter = 5000,
          run = 500, pmutation = 0.2)

plot(GA)
```

This produced the following graph:

I understand that each point on the x-axis represents the average value and the best value achieved at each iteration ("generation") - I connected some of these with red lines:

However, I am having difficulty understanding the significance of the "median" here. I would  have thought that the median would refer to a single point, but it seems like the median here is referring to a "range" of points at each iteration.

- What is the meaning of this "large green shaded region" on this graph and how exactly does it correspond to the "median"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree in that this is a somewhat misleading visualisation choice.

The explanation seems to be in the examples at the bottom of `?plot.ga-method`:

The relevant code for the shaded area (ribbon) is

```r
geom_ribbon(aes(x = iter, ymin = median, ymax = max, 
                  colour = "median", fill = "median"))
```

So the "median" ribbon seems to cover fitness values [median, max] on the y-axis.